# Understanding debugger output in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, debugging

I am setting up a simple example to show inheritance and polymorphism. I'm not sure how to explain the behavior I'm seeing in Android Studio debugger.
I have these two simple classes declared in an Empty View Activity project:

```
public class FirstClass {
    public String whoAmI = "FirstClass";
    int complexCalculation = 0;

    public FirstClass(){
        System.out.println("FirstClass Constructor");
        complexCalculation = 3^6^8^9^3;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
    public String whoAmI = "SecondClass";

    public SecondClass(){
        System.out.println("SecondClass Constructor");
    }

    public void printWhoAmI(){
        System.out.println(whoAmI);
    }

}
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
SecondClass test = new SecondClass(); 
FirstClass tester= new FirstClass(); //What will be printed to log?

tester = test; 
tester.whoAmI = "DoingStuff";
```

When placing a breakpoint on the last line and looking at the variables state, I see:
[image]
Why doesn't the attribute itself change?
Where can I further read about the behavior displayed here?

Comment: Because a) dynamic binding is not used for fields and b) fields are not overwritten on inheritance. The line `tester.whoAmI` (with `tester` declared as `FirstClass`) does not change the subclass's field.

Comment: I feel like I have a license to drive an automatic and am trying to drive a shift gear car... Reading up on dynamic binding... Thanks.
Also... why aren't you writing it as an answer? It felt like the question was crappy one, but I didn't know what to even search for :\ looks like yours is the answer no?

Comment: You have a design where you define a field of the same name (`whoAmI`) in the subclass. Fields do not get overwritten, there are now 2 fields of that name in the subclass, the subclass's one shadows the other. When you want to change the field's value from the outside, the superclass's one is picked because thats what the `tester` reference is declared as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's boil down your example to the relevant part:

```
public class FirstClass {
    public String whoAmI = "FirstClass";
}
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
    public String whoAmI = "SecondClass";
}
```

Fields do not get overwritten. That means that instance of `SecondClass` actually contain 2 fields of the same name. To distinguish them, there is a way to address them, which is why they show up as `whoAmI` and `FirstClass.whoAmI` in your debugger.

With your testing setup essentially being

```
FirstClass tester = new SecondClass();
tester.whoAmI = "DoingStuff";
```

You created a variable of type `FirstClass` that actually is a reference to an instance of `SecondClass`. However unlike methods, fields do not use dynamic binding (because no overriding), which essentially makes java go "Oh, there's actually a subclass in here. If you wanted to call a method, I would now invoke the subclass's method. But it's a field, so that mechanic is out of the picture. I will access the field of the type that this reference is declared as, which is FirstClass"

If you wanted to specifically change the subclass's field, you would need either a cast:

```
((SecondClass)tester).whoAmI = "DoingStuff";
```

or a setter like `public void setWhoAmI(String newWhoAmI)` which the superclass defines and the subclass overrides.

Comment: Going back to OOP basics...

Comment: Don't worry. The only thing you "got wrong" was to assume that fields have an override mechanic. But that only applies to methods.